# UWP Share Target open main view

Tags: uwp, sharing, uwp-xaml, data-sharing

I'm having a problem with the share target implementation in my app. It is driving me crazy.

I have in my App.xaml.cs :

```
protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShareTarget), args.ShareOperation);
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

working fine! --> next:
In my ShareTarget.cs I would "simply" like to open the apps main window if open or not open.

Currently I have:

```
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), this));
```

which only opens the Mainpage on the right side inside the "sharing" frame. I would like to open the main frame.

in the OnNavigatedTo method of MainPage

Here I tried opening a new View and dismissing the sharing frame with:

```
var newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
                await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    var frame = new Frame();
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null);
                    Window.Current.Content = frame;
                });
```

If the app is closed i get this error:

> WinRT information: Could not create a new view because the main window
>   has not yet been created

If the app is open the sharing frame on the right navigates to MainPage and closes after a few seconds.

Can't believe Microsoft has made it so difficult to form a proper implementation.

Comment: The share target is a hosted view. That means it runs inside the share pane. It is not recommended that apps try to break out of the share pane. If you really want to break out of the pane, you could do a protocol launch to yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I read about that. Is that the only possibility? How can I keep it open longer? It seems it also closes after about 10 seconds when navigated to "MainPage", no matter what.

Comment: You are not expected to navigate in your share pane. The expected UI is to show the user the sharing page directly inside the share pane as a single page, do the share operation right there, and then close the pane.

Comment: Can I somehow at least activate the main window once I want the sharing to be done? The thing is that I need to be on the mainpage to finalize the sharing.

Comment: See my first comment. You can do a protocol launch.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the only option.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks. Do you know if it's possible to directly open our app with a protocol launch, without displaying any share pane to the user? Also, how do you ask that pane to close itself once you are done? (sorry I'm  newbie, working on a cordova app)

Comment: yes possible if you don't want to share anything. look here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/#3fo5umzkrvtrXOfb.97            Otherwise for dismissing the pain, there is a dismiss command: pane.dismiss()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that seems to be possible is like @Raymon Chen suggested through creating a protocol launch.

I used this page to which explains it all pretty well:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6f0898/inter-app-communications-in-windows-10-uwp535/

It contains some typos. Please be careful.